# How to redirect after http basic auth to same url

Tags: hapi.js, http-authentication

I am able to bring a username and password pop up whenever i hit the url but i am able to verify the details with the one's present in database but not redirect it to same handler. It is stucking in else loop. **How to do that ?** After verifying if the logged in person has the right scope then it will give you response data.

My Server.js -

```
const simple_validate = function (request, reply, next) {
var credentials = auth(request);
if (!credentials || credentials.name !== 'john' || credentials.pass !== 'secret') {
    reply('Not authorized').code(401);
    reply().header('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="example"').hold();
    reply('success');
} else {
    next();
    reply('Access granted');
}
}
server.register(Basic, (err) => {
server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', { validateFunc: simple_validate });

});
```

Comment: If you check the hapijs.com website their is a guide for authentication [here](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth#authentication), the validate function is different to what you are using. Have you tried following that tutorial?

Comment: @simon-p-r Yes for some reason i was but then again i gave a try now and it started working fine now. I just have one query now that i have set the scope for that route too, now i get this if the user is not authorized "{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Insufficient scope, expected any of: ADMIN,SUPER"}" so i have to close the browser for it to ask for username and password which i don't want. if i refresh it will show same error. so what should i do ???

Comment: And thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right way of doing it.

```
const validate = function (request, email, password, callback) {
    // validate your email and password here 
    User.findUser(email,password,function(err,result){
        if(err)
            callback(null,false);
        else
            //do whatever you wanna do
    });
}

server.register(require('hapi-auth-basic'), (err) => {
       server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', { 
              validateFunc: validateApi
       });
});
```